# Gentoo how to Install all items within a package

Tags: gentoo, portage

Is it possible to install items in a package category like `games-rpg/` using a single portage command?

I've tried using things like `games-rpg/*` but I have not managed to get anything working so far.

Answer (score 0):

### General Format

```
# emerge -optionswithnospaces category/package-name-version-x.y.z
```

### Issue

You confused, package with category, which I edited.  This leads to the answer for your question.  `Emerge` itself cannot emerge packages by wildcarding the category, as the dependency checker expects at least one package.

### Solution

This leaves us with two options:

1. Write a [For Next BASH Loop](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php#for).  This requires `app-portage/portage-utils`. Something close to `emerge -av $(for name in $(qlist -IC | grep -v '^games-rpg/') etc etc`  Personally, I hate that method, as it takes time for me to debug.  There are some great scriptors on this Exchange if you decide to go this route.
2. Create a [custom package set](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/sets).  This requires a bit of tedious work, as you must manually add each package in the category, in case you don't want something from the category installed, or you can actually use what you had discovered.

`nano -w /etc/portage/sets/rpg-games`

Add the following:

```
games-rpg/*
```

And then `emerge -av @rpg-games`

Portage can actually expand the Wildcard if the wildcard is listed in the set.  I believe this works through buffer magic, but don't quote me on it.  The emerge shell forks open a temporary file, lists all the items selected by the wildcard, gathers the list and sends it as input, then closes the temporary file.

---

For more on Wildcards and Portage, read the GLOSSARY Section in `man portage`.  Here's the [online copy](https://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/portage.5.html).